# Getting an error - 'java: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown'

Tags: java, file

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

```
    int total = 0;

    File file = new File("expenditure.txt");
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        total += fileScanner.nextInt();
        }
        fileScanner.close();

    System.out.println("The total expenditure is " + total);
}
```

}

Comment: [Lesson: Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions)

Comment: Possible duplicates [error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788989/error-unreported-exception-filenotfoundexception-must-be-caught-or-declared-to) and [unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748656/unreported-exception-java-io-filenotfoundexception-must-be-caught-or-declared-t/5748802)

Comment: The Java Tutorials: [The `try-with-resources` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Surround your reading of file with a `try-catch`, sample code below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        try {
            int total = 0;

            File file = new File("expenditure.txt");
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);

            while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                total += fileScanner.nextInt();
            }
            fileScanner.close();

            System.out.println("The total expenditure is " + total);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }
}
```